# How to pass content of UITextField to another UITableViewController linked by UITabbarController

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

i am new to iOS development in swift 3 and i am encountering some trouble.
Like in  the picture below i have 2 UITableViewControllers with a textfield in the first one . The two tableViews are linked by a tabbarController And i would like to  recover the  content of the textfield to use it in the secondTableViewController. 
I dont know how to do it,  the most common tutorials about data passing explain with a button action but i would like to recover  simply the data in changing the tableView if it is possible.

I hope i was clear in my question.

[image]

Here in my first UITableViewController:

```
class InvestmentTableViewController: UITableViewController, UITabBarControllerDelegate

var someVariable: Float?

override func viewDidLoad()
{  
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.tabBarController?.delegate = self
}

  func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UITableViewController) -> Bool
{

    let selectedVC:ExtraChargesTableViewController = viewController as! ExtraChargesTableViewController
    selectedVC.totalInvest = self.someVariable

    return true

}
```

in my other tabView

```
class ExtraChargesTableViewController: UITableViewController
{

 var totalInvest: Float?
```

I dont know how to resolve this issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume you have a tabbar based project where two view controller FirstVC and SecondVC are there.
In the firstVC you have a textField, and you want that textFiled to use in SecondVC. You can pass the textFields in the `shouldSelectViewController` delegate method. So here is the FirstVC should look like

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var txtFldFirst: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self;
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
    {
        NSLog("view controller descriptionn should select = %@", viewController.description);
        let selectedVC:SecondViewController = viewController as! SecondViewController
        selectedVC.txtFld = self.txtFldFirst


        return true;
    }
```

And SecondVC should look like this

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var txtFld : UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        NSLog("text fld = %@", txtFld.text);
    }
```

Output would be the text of textField present in FirstVC.

**For UITableViewController, follow the same way**

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    var txtFldFirst:UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

        txtFldFirst = UITextField(frame: CGRectMake(20, 100, 150, 30));
        txtFldFirst.text = "Hello World"
        self.view.addSubview(txtFldFirst);

        self.tabBarController?.delegate = self;
    }


    func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool
    {
        NSLog("view controller descriptionn should select = %@", viewController.description);
        let selectedVC:SecondTableViewController = viewController as! SecondTableViewController
        selectedVC.txtFld = self.txtFldFirst


        return true;
    }
```

Second tableVC

```
import UIKit

class SecondTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var txtFld:UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()


        NSLog("text fld text = %@", self.txtFld.text);
    }
```

Happy coding ...

Comment: I tested your implementation and i can't recover my value. Is it because  my target is a UITableViewController ? or i did something wrong i tried to cast it but it crashed and when i modified the head of method the compiler told me                                             Instance method 'tabBarController(_:shouldSelect:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'tabBarController(_:shouldSelect:)' of protocol 'UITabBarControllerDelegate'

Comment: I tested it by taking two tableVC also, it is working. If you are facing issue please let me know. The procedure is same.

Comment: Did you change header of function or let viewController for parameter ?.In fact  i took variable which is result of calculation thanks to UITextFIeld and i tried to pass it but when i click on the other item i reload data and my variable is nil . thanks for your time.

Comment: i reedit my answer if you don't understand  what i am saying .

Comment: if i set like this Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1063370c0) to 'HappyBanker.ExtraChargesTableViewController'

Comment: I have added my code with UITableVC, have a look
i am able pass the txtfld, by the where did you take your txtFld?

Comment: In fact i would like to make a sum of things in my first TableViewController so instead of take the result of textfield i take the result  variable itself and after that i follow your implementation but i dont understand if i must change second parameter of the method tabBarController(UITabBarController, shouldSelect: UIViewController) in tableViewCOntroller or leave it like that ? because if i change it  warning me with Instance method 'tabBarController(_:shouldSelect:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'tabBarController(_:shouldSelect:)'

Comment: my own txtFld is another variable to calculate another thing I dont know if i am  enough understanding

Comment: Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x105ff80c0) to ''MyProjet.SecondUITableView'

Comment: You can see the edit starts from bold text. I think your textField is inside the table cell. is it? in my case the text field is not in table cell.
Again i saw your delegate method for tabbar delegate, why did you modify the delegate mehod (like you have taken UITableViewController in shouldSelectViewController), UItableViewController inherit from UIViewController so there wont be any issue if you keep the delegate method unchanged. See my implementation

Comment: I understood about not to change method of tabBarDelegate , i have severals cells in my firstTableView and i did sum of them and i placed it an optional variable (var someVariable: Float?) i just need to recover its value in the second TableView but when i tried to push the second item of my tabbar i encountered a signal SIGABERT i dont know why

Comment: At Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x105ff80c0) to ''MyProjet.SecondUITableView' –  At the line                                                     let selectedVC:SecondViewController = viewController as! SecondViewController

Comment: even with the TextFields i can't pass to the other tableViewController maybe it is because i am working with swift 3 and xcode8 beta 6

Comment: I tried for test to modify ViewController to TableViewCOntroller and i can go to the other tab i dont have the sigabert error but i can't recover my value. Honestly  I don't understand how to fix that issue

Comment: maybe it is because my first TableViewController is embed to a navigationController that himself embed to a tabBarController.

Comment: @idealisticdreamer2, you are getting the error as the variable you have taken is in tableViewController, but you are trying to pass it to UINavigationController. in the delegate method of tabbar, find the navigation controller first, then get the root controller of navigation controller, which will give you the TableVC, then you pass the variable you want look the code here to be written inside the delegate method

Comment: Here is the code ============

        let navCntrl:UINavigationController = viewController as! UINavigationController
        
        let selectedVC:SecondTableViewController = navCntrl.viewControllers.first as! SecondTableViewController
        selectedVC.txtFld = self.txtFldFirst

Comment: Let me know, if it resolves your issue, or else can you shared your code with me, I can help you out in that way

Comment: It is finally working in that way  but now when i tried to go back to previous view i am encountering another error.

Comment: thanks anyway because you pulled me out of bas situations

Comment: It might be due to the delegate method getting called when you click the first tab and it tries to pass the value, the variable is in second controller.

Else you can set the tabbar delegate to nil after assigning the value to the variiable of secondVC and in FirstVC set the delegate in viewWillAppear instead of viewdidLoad. Please upvote the answer

Comment: my last error  Could not cast value of type 'MyApp.FirstTableViewCOntroller' (0x10bb64598) to 'MyApp.SecondTableViewController'  i suppose its an similar issue to my previous problem. I will look it up tomorrow but if you have an idea i am not against. Thank you for your time.

Comment: i can't now because i dont have enough reputation but when i will have enough point i will do. Thanks again !! :)

Comment: @idealisticdreamer2, That is what i told you. set the delegate to nil after passing the value
And set the delegate to self in viewWillAppear of FirstVC instead of viewDidLoad